# What is the difference between ensym and enquo when programming with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval

Relatively new to tidy evaluation and while the functions I'm making work, I want to know why different helper functions are used.  For example, what is the difference between `enquo` and `ensym`? In the function I made below to capture daily average and moving average they're interchangeable:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(rlang)
library(zoo)

manipulate_for_ma <- function(data, group_var, da_col_name, summary_var, ma_col_name) {
  group_var <- ensym(group_var) 
  summary_var <- enquo(summary_var)
  da_col_name <- ensym(da_col_name) 
  ma_col_name <- enquo(ma_col_name)
  
  data %>% 
    group_by(!!group_var) %>%
    summarise(!!da_col_name := mean(!!summary_var, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
    mutate(!!ma_col_name := rollapply(!!da_col_name,
                                      30,
                                      mean,
                                      na.rm = TRUE,
                                      partial = TRUE,
                                      fill = NA)) %>% 
    rename(date = !!group_var)
}

lakers %>%
 mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
 manipulate_for_ma(group_var = date,
                   da_col_name = points_per_play_da,
                   summary_var = points,
                   points_per_play_ma)

# A tibble: 78 x 3
   date       points_per_play_da points_per_play_ma
   <date>                  <dbl>              <dbl>
 1 2008-10-28              0.413              0.458
 2 2008-10-29              0.431              0.459
 3 2008-11-01              0.408              0.456
 4 2008-11-05              0.386              0.457
```

I've read about `enquo` [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20220507135634/https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/modifying-inputs.html) and `ensym` [here](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html).  Is the difference that `ensym` is more restrictive and only takes strings or string-like objects?

Comment: If it only takes strings, then how is it working with `group_var = date`

Comment: @akrun--good point, further emphasizing my lack of understanding here.  This is what Hadley says in advanced R: Sometimes you only want to allow the user to specify a variable name, not an arbitrary expression. In this case, you can use `ensym()` or `ensyms()`. These are variants of `enexpr()` and `enexprs()` that check the captured expression is either symbol or a string (which is converted to a symbol67).`ensym()` and `ensyms()` throw an error if given anything else.

Comment: It would take both strings and non-strings.   You can change `date` to `"date"` and check with `ensym` and `enquo`  The former works, while the latter gives error

Comment: @akrun-so is the only difference that `ensym` allows you to pass strings as arguments *as well as* symbols?

Comment: By looking at the help page `ensym() and ensyms() are variants of enexpr() and enexprs() that check the captured expression is either a string (which they convert to symbol) or a symbol.`  `quo and enquo() are similar to their expr counterparts but capture both the expression and its environment in an object called a quosure.`

Comment: Also note that when programming such functions with dplyr, one is probably better off using the new curly-curly style: `manipulate_for_ma <- function(data, group_var, da_col_name, summary_var, ma_col_name) {
  data %>% 
    group_by({{ group_var }}) %>%
    summarise({{ da_col_name }} := mean({{ summary_var }}, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% ...
}` . Reference: https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another take :

```r
library(rlang)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

test <- function(x){
  Species <- "bar"
  cat("--- enquo builds a quosure from any expression\n")
  print(enquo(x))
  cat("--- ensym captures a symbol or a literal string as a symbol\n")
  print(ensym(x))
  cat("--- evaltidy will evaluate the quosure in its environment\n")
  print(eval_tidy(enquo(x)))
  cat("--- evaltidy will evaluate a symbol locally\n")
  print(eval_tidy(ensym(x)))
  cat("--- but both work fine where the environment doesn't matter\n")
  identical(select(iris,!!ensym(x)), select(iris,!!enquo(x)))
}

Species = "foo"
test(Species)
#> --- enquo builds a quosure from any expression
#> <quosure>
#> expr: ^Species
#> env:  global
#> --- ensym captures a symbol or a literal string as a symbol
#> Species
#> --- evaltidy will evaluate the quosure in its environment
#> [1] "foo"
#> --- evaltidy will evaluate a symbol locally
#> [1] "bar"
#> --- but both work fine where the environment doesn't matter
#> [1] TRUE

test("Species")
#> --- enquo builds a quosure from any expression
#> <quosure>
#> expr: ^"Species"
#> env:  empty
#> --- ensym captures a symbol or a literal string as a symbol
#> Species
#> --- evaltidy will evaluate the quosure in its environment
#> [1] "Species"
#> --- evaltidy will evaluate a symbol locally
#> [1] "bar"
#> --- but both work fine where the environment doesn't matter
#> [1] TRUE
test(paste0("Spec","ies"))
#> --- enquo builds a quosure from any expression
#> <quosure>
#> expr: ^paste0("Spec", "ies")
#> env:  global
#> --- ensym captures a symbol or a literal string as a symbol
#> Only strings can be converted to symbols
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: @BenG: Not to make things more complicated, but there's also `enexpr`, which is somewhere between `ensym` and `enquo`: 1) Both `enexpr` and `enquo` allow for arbitrary expressions, while `ensym` only allows for "variable name"-like expression; 2) Both `enexpr` and `ensym` do NOT capture the environment, making their evaluation context-dependent, while `enquo` expressions will always evaluate the same way everywhere.

Comment: Indeed, `enexpr()` is like `ensym()` on symbols, but `enexpr()`  allows complex expressions unlike `ensym()`, because of this lack of restriction it cannot guess that when we feed a string literal we mean a symbol. `enexpr()` is a lot like the single argument `substitute()` excepts that it supports the unquoting via `!!` in the function arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one example illustrating one difference (namely that `enquo` captures the calling environment and `ensym` doesn't). Hopefully it speaks for itself:

```
library(rlang)

f <- function(x) {
  foo <- 42
  print(eval_tidy(quo(!! ensym(x))))
  print(eval_tidy(quo(!! enquo(x))))
}
foo <- 3
f(foo)
# [1] 42
# [1] 3
```

Or the slightly more convoluted:

```r
library(rlang)

myenv <- new.env()

local(envir = myenv, {
  foo <- 17
  g <- function(x) {
    print(eval_tidy(quo(!! ensym(x))))
    print(eval_tidy(quo(!! enquo(x))))
  }
})

foo <- 123
myenv$g(foo)
#> [1] 17
#> [1] 123
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The difference is often not noticeable when using dplyr since it is foolproof enough to always look up names in the context of the `.data` argument first.

Comment: I don't really get it--as it is I'm only just starting to understand quosures intuitively.  I'm sure as I start to use it more it'll make more sense.  One thing I'm starting to think about which I'm not sure is correct is that I have to use these `rlang` quoting functions with the end user mind.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to use rlang. Maybe use the curly-curly syntax instead, that is one level of abstraction higher, as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57960245/what-is-the-difference-between-ensym-and-enquo-when-programming-with-dplyr/57990624?noredirect=1#comment102392073_57960245

Comment: A recommended read if you don't mind going down the rabbit hole is http://blog.obeautifulcode.com/R/How-R-Searches-And-Finds-Stuff/ . I seem to recall it's even referenced by Hadley in his book. Pointer: it has to do with the different sorts of environments that are involved with functions (enclosing, binding, calling...). Or go back a few chapters to https://adv-r.hadley.nz/environments.html#special-environments