# using quasiquotation in functions with formula interface

Tags: r, tidyverse, rlang, quasiquotes

I want to write a custom function that can take `bare` and `"string"` inputs, and can handle both functions with and without the formula interface.

## custom function example

```
# setup
set.seed(123)
library(tidyverse)

# custom function
foo <- function(data, x, y) {
  # function without formula
  print(table(data %>% dplyr::pull({{ x }}), data %>% dplyr::pull({{ y }})))

  # function with formula
  print(
    broom::tidy(stats::t.test(
      formula = rlang::new_formula({{ rlang::ensym(y) }}, {{ rlang::ensym(x) }}),
      data = data
    ))
  )
}
```

## bare

works for both functions with and without formula interface

```r
foo(mtcars, am, cyl)
#>    
#>      4  6  8
#>   0  3  4 12
#>   1  8  3  2

#> # A tibble: 1 x 10
#>   estimate estimate1 estimate2 statistic p.value parameter conf.low conf.high
#>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     1.87      6.95      5.08      3.35 0.00246      25.9    0.724      3.02
#> # ... with 2 more variables: method <chr>, alternative <chr>
```

## string

works for both functions with and without formula interface

```r
foo(mtcars, "am", "cyl")
#>    
#>      4  6  8
#>   0  3  4 12
#>   1  8  3  2

#> # A tibble: 1 x 10
#>   estimate estimate1 estimate2 statistic p.value parameter conf.low conf.high
#>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     1.87      6.95      5.08      3.35 0.00246      25.9    0.724      3.02
#> # ... with 2 more variables: method <chr>, alternative <chr>
```

## as colnames

works only for functions without the formula interface

```r
foo(mtcars, colnames(mtcars)[9], colnames(mtcars)[2])
#>    
#>      4  6  8
#>   0  3  4 12
#>   1  8  3  2

#> Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols
#> Backtrace:
#>     x
#>  1. \-global::foo(mtcars, colnames(mtcars)[9], colnames(mtcars)[2])
#>  2.   +-base::print(...)
#>  3.   +-broom::tidy(...)
#>  4.   +-stats::t.test(...)
#>  5.   +-rlang::new_formula(...)
#>  6.   \-rlang::ensym(y)
```

How can I modify the original function so that it will work with all the above-mentioned ways of entering the inputs and for both kinds of functions used?

Comment: you're on the verge of being too flexible: `x <- 'am'; y <- 'cyl'; foo(mtcars, x, y)`

Comment: @rawr or even more confusing: `am <- 'disp'; cyl <- 'gear'; foo(mtcars, am, cyl)`. What's supposed to happen there? Are the parameter supposed to be evaluated to their string values or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nice philosophy of `rlang` is that you get to control when you want values to be evaluated via the `!!` and `{{}}` operators. You seem to want to make a function that takes strings, symbols, and (possibly evaluated) expressions all in the same parameter. Using symbols or bare strings is actually easy with `ensym` but also wanting to allow for code like `colnames(mtcars)[9]` that has to be *evaulated* before returning a string is the problem. This potentially can be quite confusing. For example, what's the behavior you expect when you run the following?

```
am <- 'disp'
cyl <- 'gear'
foo(mtcars, am, cyl)
```

You could write a helper function if you want to assume all "calls" should be evaluated but symbols and literals should not. Here's a "cleaner" function

```
clean_quo <- function(x) {
  if (rlang::quo_is_call(x)) {
    x <- rlang::eval_tidy(x)
  } else if (!rlang::quo_is_symbolic(x)) {
    x <- rlang::quo_get_expr(x)
  }
  if (is.character(x)) x <- rlang::sym(x)
  if (!rlang::is_quosure(x)) x <- rlang::new_quosure(x)
  x
}
```

and you could use that in your function with

```
foo <- function(data, x, y) {
  x <- clean_quo(rlang::enquo(x))
  y <- clean_quo(rlang::enquo(y))

  # function without formula
  print(table(data %>% dplyr::pull(!!x), data %>% dplyr::pull(!!y)))

  # function with formula
  print(
    broom::tidy(stats::t.test(
      formula = rlang::new_formula(rlang::quo_get_expr(y), rlang::quo_get_expr(x)),
      data = data
    ))
  )
}
```

Doing so will allow all these to return the same values

```
foo(mtcars, am, cyl)
foo(mtcars, "am", "cyl")
foo(mtcars, colnames(mtcars)[9], colnames(mtcars)[2])
```

But you are probably just delaying possible other problems. I would not recommend over-interpreting user intentions with this kind of code. That's why it's better to explicitly allow them to un-escape themselves. Perhaps provide two different versions of the function that can be used with parameter that require evaluation and those that do not.

Comment: Thanks. I am supporting all the different ways to enter arguments because a lot of users of my functions expect them to work. This is because of their prior experience with the `tidyverse` functions, which can indeed accept symbols, strings, and expressions.

Answer (score 3):

I have to agree with @MrFlick and others about inherent ambiguity when mixing standard and non-standard evaluation. (I also pointed this out in your [similar question from a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58823919/300187).)

However, one can argue that `dplyr::select()` works with symbols, strings and expressions of the form `colnames(.)[.]`. If you absolutely must have the same interface, then you can leverage [tidyselect](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/articles/syntax.html) to resolve your inputs:

```
library( rlang )
library( tidyselect )

ttest <- function(data, x, y) {
  ## Identify locations of x and y in data, get column names as symbols
  s <- eval_select( expr(c({{x}},{{y}})), data ) %>% names %>% syms

  ## Use the corresponding symbols to build the formula by hand
  broom::tidy(stats::t.test(
    formula = new_formula( s[[2]], s[[1]] ),
    data = data
  ))
}

## All three now work
ttest( mtcars, am, cyl )
ttest( mtcars, "am", "cyl" )
ttest( mtcars, colnames(mtcars)[9], colnames(mtcars)[2] )
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for noticing that. This was very much inspired by `dplyr::select`! I expect users who have experience with tidyvese to also expect my functions will work the same way! And it would be nice if I could support that.