# Multiple highchart with similar structure in R

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, shinydashboard

I have multiple highcharts in my shiny app and the structure is similar in all of them, so I'm trying to use a function to generalise:

1. In my data file:

**Edit**

> ```
> set.seed(5)      
> data <- data.frame(id=1:10, 
>                period=seq(2011,2020, 1),
>                program=rep(LETTERS[1:2], 5),
>                total=rnorm(10))
> ```

```
    gral <- function(df,x,y,group,theme){
    highchart() %>%
      hc_xAxis(type = "category") %>%
      hc_add_series(df, "line",
                    hcaes(x = x, y = y
                          ,group = group),
                    dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE,
                                      style = list(fontSize = '13px'))
      ) %>% 
      hc_legend(enabled = TRUE) %>% 
      hc_tooltip(shared = TRUE, crosshairs = TRUE
                 ,style = list(fontSize = "18px")
      ) %>%
      hc_add_theme(theme) }
```

2. In my server file (for each highchart)

> ```
>       output$usuariosgral <- renderHighchart({  gral(df = data, x = period, y = total,
>       group = program, theme = hc_theme_elementary()) })
> ```

But it is not working, anyone knows why?

**Finally, I found the answer here, in case it is useful to anyone --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/64392483/13529820**

Just need to use the function `ensym` from library `rlang`. So in my code jus changed the `hcaes` line to this:

> `hcaes(x = !!rlang::ensym(x), y = !!rlang::ensym(y), group = !!rlang::ensym(group))`

Comment: Can you make this example self-contained by including data and complete app code? Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: You will just need to review [shiny app layouts](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html#grid-layouts-in-depth) and know how you want to organize your code, Shiny is broken into 12 columns you can divide anyway you like, just has to fit your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64392483/13529820) in case it is useful to anyone.

Just need to use the function `ensym` from library `rlang`. So in my code jus changed the `hcaes` line to this:

> `hcaes(x = !!rlang::ensym(x), y = !!rlang::ensym(y), group = !!rlang::ensym(group))`

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue: `hcaes` is based on `ggplot2::aes` and acts similarly, luckily, you can access it as a string, `ggplot2` has `aes_string` and highcharter has `hcaes_string`

```
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)

gral  <- function(df,x,y,group,theme){
    highchart() %>%
        hc_xAxis(type = "category") %>%
        hc_add_series(df, "line",
                      hcaes_string(x = x, y = y, group = group),
                      dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE,
                                        style = list(fontSize = '13px'))) %>% 
        hc_legend(enabled = TRUE) %>% 
        hc_tooltip(shared = TRUE, crosshairs = TRUE,style = list(fontSize = "18px")) %>%
        hc_add_theme(theme) 
}

ui <- basicPage(
    column(12,
           highchartOutput('usuariosgral')
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$usuariosgral <- renderHighchart({  
        gral(df = mtcars,x ='mpg',y = 'disp',group ='cyl',theme = hc_theme_elementary())
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried run with `hcaes_string` instead of `hcaes`, but even with your example didn't work. Thank you for your answer, it helped me to find the answer (in my question is the solution that I found)

Comment: in that case, its best if u create an answer and accept it yourself